# Solving an ODE without a boundary condition

Tags: ode

I have an ODE without a boundary condition:

$\small\left(\frac{d}{dr}C(r)\right)^4-2C(r)\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dr}C(r)\right)^2+2\left(\frac{d}{dr}C(r)\right)C(r)^2\left(\frac{d^3}{dr^3}C(r)\right)-4\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r)\right)^2C(r)^2+12C(r)^2\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r)\right)-8C(r)^2=0$

I only know the behavior of the function at infinity. Would you please help me to solve the ODE? I can send it to everybody who like help me.
Thanks a lot,
M.KH.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this equation in any form.  Could you please post the equation and the conditions here.

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete ... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: There is an image button near the curly brackets in the top editing toolbar.

Comment: I could attach it. please help me dears.

Comment: I know that function C(r) is 1 in infinity,just this.

Comment: Well, if you want a closed form solution of that equation I would say "99 % sure it's impossible" only looking at its length, but maybe you can simplify it in some way.

Comment: How can I simplify it?

Comment: Can you re-state it as first-order differential equations, then start $r$ at 0, and run any ODE solver in the reverse direction? (I think DLSODA will do that, or DVERK.) Also you could do change of variables to, say, $x = -r$.

Comment: To  Mike Dunlavey : I think I can't apply the infinity condition to solve it, and it must be applied manually after the finding answer. And I don't Know anything about DLSODA and DVERK. I worked with Maple and MATLAB a little.

Comment: If you're trying to solve this ODE analytically (as opposed to numerically), you might get better answers at [mathematics.stackexchange.com](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: To:Christian Clason. Yes, I prefer to solve it analytically.

Comment: Dear friends, Could everybody help me to solve it numerically? I think it probably hasn't any analytic solution.

Comment: If you'd like to solve it numerically, please edit the question to reflect your inquiry. Until then, I'm voting to close as this is clearly more appropriate for math.SE.

Comment: @user4416: To solve it numerically, just re-express it as first-order, replace r with -x, set C to 1, and run it as long as you like. What you will see is the answer, with the x-axis reflected.

Comment: To Mike Dunlavey: But I don't know how I must solve it numerically. what is the command in MATLAB or Mathematica ?

Answer (score 5):

Since your ODE is already nonlinear, you can transform the coordinate variable, for example using
$$
  r = 1/s
$$
and defining 
$$
  C(r) = C(r(s)) = \tilde C(s).
$$
Then replace every occurrence of $d/dr$ by $ds/dr d/ds=-1/s^2 d/ds$ to obtain an ODE for $\tilde C$ only in $s$ instead of $r$. Now note that the boundary condition $C(\infty)=1$ corresponds to $\tilde C(0)=1$, so you can now forward integrate $\tilde C$ from zero to whatever value you care about, and then compute $C(r) = \tilde C(1/r)$.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will do it and if I couldn't solve it, I will ask you again. Best regards.